# How to add an access key in AWS? Menu item missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to use AWS toolkit in a my NetBrains IDEs. To do this, I need an AdministratorAccess user with a set of access keys.

I have followed [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/setup-toolkit.html) and am on [3. Create an access key for the user, if you don't have an access key for that user already.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey)

My navigation bar should have a "Security credentials" option like this:

[image]

But instead, it looks like this (some values redacted):
[image]

Since I don't have a security credentials option, how do I add/ get my security keys?

If there's another, less painful way to use AWS toolkit, I'm open to that as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ah! You're using SSO to connect with AWS. See: [How to retrieve short-term credentials for CLI use with AWS IAM Identity Center | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-single-sign-on-now-enables-command-line-interface-access-for-aws-accounts-using-corporate-credentials/)